# Download online video js

Tags: html, video.js

I don't know if this is the right place to ask such a question, but I want to download an [online video](https://neomagraduationceremony.captag.events/FSBRXR/#/r/cb5c2d7e-d818-4a82-9293-4078e5805156) of my graduation. I tried to look up the source code and in inspect option in google chrome but I didn't succeed. Is there any way to download the video?

Comment: It uses [M3U8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) which can be [downloaded and converted](https://www.5kplayer.com/vlc/m3u8-vlc.htm) using [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Just input [this link](https://manifest-gce-us-east1-production.fastly.mux.com/0218c6NcztSajfGUV5w5jwAS00amZ9O8NIUSTTpds02qOalH1u72zTIFcgrxCo4q8pRaYN341cYNqWg02wAkXn3hCoMGyvOl6S7y/rendition.m3u8?cdn=fastly&exclude_pdt=false&expires=1657450800&skid=default&signature=NjJjYWIxMzBfZmQyYjQwM2I0ZmFiOWNlZmRkODQyMzczMGIyOWM1MzRlYWEwN2FlMjc1ZTdhMGMwZGM2MmI2ODM0MjQ1ZWRhZQ==).

Comment: @NiklasE. Thank you it is working, can you post an answer and show me how did you get the *.m3u8 file please

Comment: I think you've got it in the developer tool files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page uses [HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) deploying the [M3U8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) file format. After obtaining the link to the M3U8 file, it can be downloaded and converted with other software libaries also supporting HLS (e.g. [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) `ffmpeg -i "https://….m3u8?…" output.mp4`).

You can extract the `.m3u8` URL using Chrome Dev Tools, which allow you to browse loaded resources in your browser:

> #### Log network activity
>
> Reload the page. The Network panel logs all network activity in the **Network Log**.
>
> [image]
>
> – [**Documentation › Chrome DevTools › Network**](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load)

Once opened with <kbd>F12</kbd>, you can press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload all resources and use the search option to filter for `m3u8`:

[image]

Comment: I like the solution with the command line thank you